# Unity application with aar installed 2 apk on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, aar

I can make sure unity packageName and the aar package name totally the same,but why here comes 2 apk and uninstall one will lead the other to be uninstall.
below is my mainifest，

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bojoy.xplan">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/step_detector" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="@string/step_counter" android:required="false"/>


<application >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any custom buildsetting?

Comment: no，2 new project ，everything seems to be default